# Отображение количества столбцов sqlite3

Tags: python, aiogram, sqlite3

Пишу бота на `aiogram` используя `sqlite`.
Хочу отобразить количество товара по pricetag, но выдает ошибку.
Вот функция с запросом:

```
def mag1(self, pricetag):
    with self.connection:
        self.cursor.execute("SELECT COUNT(pricetag) FROM prod_1cat GROUP BY pricetag HAVING pricetag = 10")
        result = self.cursor.fetchone()
        if result:
            return int(result[0][0])
```

Однако вместо количества строк пишет ошибку

```
<bound method Database.mag1 of <db.Database object at 0x00000228E95C6370>>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Из кода не видно, что у вас в `self.cursor` находится. Непонятно для чего у вас строка `with self.connection:`. И почему вы не используете результат `self.cursor.execute("SELECT ...")`. То, что вы посчитали ошибкой - на самом деле строковое представление метода `mag1` объекта класса `Database`.
Попробуйте так.

```
import sqlite3

class Database:
    def __init__(self, db_path):
        try:
            self.connection = sqlite3.connect(db_path)
            print("Соединение с SQLite установлено")
        except sqlite3.Error as error:
            print("Ошибка при подключении к sqlite", error)

    def close_connection(self):
        if self.connection:
            self.connection.close()
            print("Соединение с SQLite закрыто")

    def mag1(self, pricetag):
        with self.connection as con:
            result = con.cursor().execute("SELECT COUNT(pricetag) FROM prod_1cat WHERE pricetag = ?",(pricetag,)).fetchone()
            if result:
                return result[0]


db = Database('sqlite_python.db')  # ваш путь к БД
print(db.mag1(10))
db.close_connection()
```

**Данные:**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Результат:**

```
Соединение с SQLite установлено
2
Соединение с SQLite закрыто
```

Comment: Спасибо, действительно помогло